# Issue with regexp substr function in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I have a `SELECT` statement which contains `regexp_substr` in it

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR
      ('hello, main.proc.standarad_name(ename),main.proc.standarad_val(eno)',
       '[,](.*)[(]eno[)]',
       1,
       1,
       'i',
       1
      )
FROM DUAL

Expected Output: main.proc.standarad_val
Actual Output: main.proc.standarad_name(ename),main.proc.standarad_val
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you better the logics behind the needed result? Do you need the string after the second comma, the last part of the string, ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `.*` by `[^,]*` to match any character except `,`.

[can be checked here, rextester](http://rextester.com/PYNUL37456)